# Any better way to determine the type based on T and subclass

Tags: c#, generics, .net-2.0

Writing a bit of code that deals with a Response and a Request. Both can be in the form of XML, and both can be in the form of a C# Object created through a transform and serialization. (this is .NET 2.0)

Response and Request are base implementations of larger message types. Right now I have GetEligibility and FindCandidates.

Example of the Model.MessageModel classes used below:

```
public partial class GetEligibilityResponseMessage : ResponseMessage

public partial class ResponseMessage : Message
```

Because I won't want to duplicate my mapping functionality I've decided to use generics to simplify the process, and it's working out great:

**Base Class Code**

```
    public virtual Model.MessageModel.Message MapToModel<T>(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        V3Mapper mapper = new V3Mapper();
        Model.MessageModel.Message message = mapper.MapToDomainModel<T>(xml, Environment) as Model.MessageModel.Message;
        return message;
    }

    public virtual XmlDocument MapToXml<T>(Model.MessageModel.Message message)
    {
        V3Mapper mapper = new V3Mapper();
        XmlDocument xml= mapper.MapToV3Message<T>(message, Environment);
        return xml;
    }
```

When my code is first called, it has an XML document. I know this document will be mapped as a request, and so I call a virtual method that is overriden (and I think it's ugly). The reason to keep the mapping code in the base is to not duplicate code, yet I find I am doing the exact thing I want to avoid by the following:

**GetEligibility : BaseClass**

```
   public override Model.MessageModel.Message MapToModel<T>(XmlDocument xml)
    {   
        if(typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(GetEligibilityResponseMessage)))
        {
            return base.MapToModel<GetEligibilityResponseMessage>(xml);
        }
        else if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(GetEligibilityRequestMessage))) 
        {
            return base.MapToModel<GetEligibilityRequestMessage>(xml);
        }
        return null;//because this is a quick code snippet
    }
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?  I always know if I'm working with a Response or Request. I want to leave the functionality open so it's not too tightly-coupled, but at the same time have it functional and fast.

This will be implemented by a number of different message types, and I really hate copy/paste style of coding, so an elegant solution would be great, but I'm not sure if there is one. (.NET 2.0)

Comment: My advice, don't do that. That will just lead to confusing code.

Comment: As opposed to having pretty much the same 2 functions copy/pasted in 10 different classes? not my cup of tea either. I'm not a fan of the last code block, hence the reason for asking about it

Comment: Provided that there are no classes derived from `GetEligibilityResponseMessage` and `GetEligibilityRequestMessage`, your overriden `MapToModel` is equivalent to the base one, with the exception of type checking. What is the point of overriding `MapToModel` method, then? Is it just for type checking?

Comment: Yes the only reason I overrode it was to get the correct type, otherwise the base code would not know what it was supposed to use. Still trying to see if there's a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to avoid having to check types before calling your generic method. Below is a quick usage example:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Generic<T>(T toDisplay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nHere it is: {0}", toDisplay);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Generic");
        MethodInfo miConstructed = mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(DateTime));

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        miConstructed.Invoke(null, new object[] { now });
    }
}
```

Notice that I used **typeof(DateTime)**, but in your case you can replace that by **typeof(T)** to achieve the desired loosely-coupled solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to validate the request and response types, you can have your base class know about that:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private readonly Type _requestType;
    private readonly Type _responseType;

    protected BaseClass(Type requestType, Type responseType)
    {
        _requestType = requestType;
        _responseType = responseType;
    }

    public T MapToModel<T>(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != _requestType && typeof(T) != _responseType)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid type");

        var mapper = new V3Mapper();
        return mapper.MapToDomainModel<T>(xml, Environment);
    }
}

public GetEligibility : BaseClass
{
    public GetEligibility() 
        : base(typeof(GetEligibilityRequestMessage), typeof(GetEligibilityResponseMessage))
    {}
}
```

You can even go a step further and make `BaseClass` generic, with dedicated `MapToRequest` and `MapToResponse` methods which know what to return:

```
public class BaseClass<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest:RequestMessage,
          TResponse:ResponseMessage
{
    public TRequest MapToRequest(XmlDocument xml)
    { return MapToModel<TRequest>(xml); }

    public TResponse MapToResponse(XmlDocument xml)
    { return MapToModel<TResponse>(xml); }

    private T MapToModel<T>(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        var mapper = new V3Mapper();
        return mapper.MapToDomainModel<T>(xml, Environment);        
    }
}

public GetEligibility : BaseClass<GetEligibilityRequestMessage, GetEligibilityResponseMessage>
{}
```